# Oracle 12.2 - Replacement of NOPARTITION feature

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-partitioning, ora-00933, database-sequence

I have Oracle version 12.2.0.1.0

We have generic script which create sequence that need to be reuse for different objects (by renaming sequence name):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE NAME_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 100 CACHE 200 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

This script isn't working with below error until I remove `NOPARTITION` :

```
   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I found in AskTom that the [NOPARTITION is not supported in 12.2](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9523071800346490539)

> there's been various of things in previous versions of the database that are no longer relevant/supported

Why it's not supported and/or what is the replacement of this feature ?

If there's no replacement can you state why this feature shouldn't be used?

Comment: The actual question is: why do you think you need it? Especially taking into account that `nopartition` wasn't even documented in previous versions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have a "legacy" script which i want to make sure I'm not missing anything significant if I remove `NOPARTITION `

Comment: That's the risk when you use undocumented features...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (no)partition option for sequences was *never* documented. And thus never supported.

There was a bug in 12.1 which exposed this via dbms_metadata. It no longer happens in 12.2

Undocumented features can (and as this proves) do change without warning. Using them is strictly at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a dbms_metadata.get_ddl from database version 12.1 and want to use it in 12.2 then a NOPARTITION is supplied. Now we have to remove it.