# SQL command not properly ended error : Error: ORA-00933

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the query i am trying to execute..

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "GARY"."TABL_PROD_DWH_SEQ" 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOPARTITION;
```

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>
> CREATE SEQUENCE "GARY"."TABL_PROD_DWH_SEQ"
> MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999999999
> INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOPARTITION;
>
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
> 'Cause:
> 'Action:

Comment: Oracle docs say the maxvalue can have 28 or fewer digits for positive values , but you have 32 digits set.

Comment: @GARY hi, I think you forgot to select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Oracle are you using?  `NOPARTITION` doesn't ring a bell.  It might only be available on more recent versions.

You can also use `NOMAXVALUE`.  That seems more intuitive than your arbitrary value.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanaton

Please see the following question/answer: [Oracle 12.2 - Replacement of NOPARTITION feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731498/oracle-12-2-replacement-of-nopartition-feature)

**Your problem is NOPARTITION.**

It is a non-documented unsupported feature after a version of Oracle (I think 12).

Also see: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9523071800346490539

### Test

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1afa88 (Oracle 11g R2)

The below does work:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "TABL_PROD_DWH_SEQ" 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20
NOORDER NOCYCLE
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already been told most of the things. Let me add a few more words.

Your problem looks like the one that happens when people use parameters they don't quite understand. I apologize if I sound *impolite*, but - that's my impression. Why? Because of the look of that `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement.

No living person I know has ever manually written it

- using double quotes around uppercase owner and sequence name,
- nor have they used such a `MAXVALUE` (heck, it is *indefinite* anyway),
- nor they want to explicitly *remind* Oracle that default increment is `1`,
- as well as cache (which is `20` by default)
- not to mention other options that are *default* anyway

Apart from `start with`, everything else is **default** anyway so you could have used

```
SQL> create sequence tabl_prod_dwh_seq start with 21;

Sequence created.

SQL> select tabl_prod_dwh_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        21

SQL> select tabl_prod_dwh_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        22

SQL>
```

and get the same result. So ... have a look at documentation related to **your database version**, try to follow it, don't do what's not allowed (or undocumented), keep it as simple as possible and you'll be good.